# Upload a downloaded file

Tags: browser, attachments

I downloaded a zip-file with the browser to my phone. Now I want to either upload it to a web site (form POST) or mail it as an attachment.

In the stock browser (HTC Desire with Android 2.2) I can only choose to upload from Gallery, Voice recorder, or Music.

In the Gmail app I can only attach photos and in the Exchange app can't seem to attach downloaded files either.

And finally, in the list of downloaded files in the browser I can only choose to Open (fails for zip) or Delete the file.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a File Explorer, say [EStrongs File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), and you would be able to upload arbitrary file from the browser or attach files to Gmail.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that.